# Visualizing decision tree with feature names

Tags: visualization, decision-trees

```py
    from scipy.sparse import hstack

    X_tr1 = hstack((X_train_cc_ohe, X_train_csc_ohe, X_train_grade_ohe, 
                    X_train_price_norm, X_train_tnppp_norm, X_train_essay_bow, 
                    X_train_pt_bow)).tocsr()

    X_te1 = hstack((X_test_cc_ohe, X_test_csc_ohe, X_test_grade_ohe, 
                    X_test_price_norm, X_test_tnppp_norm, X_test_essay_bow, 
                    X_test_pt_bow)).tocsr()
```

`X_train_cc_ohe` and all are vectorized categorical data, and `X_train_pt_bow` is bag of words vectorized text data.

Now, I applied a decision tree classifier on this model and got this:

[image]

I took `max_depth` as 3 just for visualization purposes.

**My question is: I would like to get feature names in my output instead of index as X2599, X4 etc. I know I can do it by `vect.get_feature_names()` as input to `export_graphviz`, vect is object of `CountVectorizer()`, since I already merged this vectorized data using hstack. Now how do you get feature names in this decision tree?**

Comment: It would be helpful to include your visualization code.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot with [`sklearn.tree.plot_tree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html), there is a parameter for `feature_names`:

> feature_names: list of strings, default=None
> Names of each of the features. If None, generic names will be used (“X[0]”, “X[1]”, …).

Answer (score 0):

`hstack` preserves the order of the columns, so you can piece together the feature names for each of your component arrays.  `OneHotEncoder` (if that's what you used) and `CountVectorizer` both support `get_feature_names`, so concatenating the lists of feature names should be possible.  To give full details would require more details about how each of the arrays was generated.  You might consider using `ColumnTransformer` in the future, which handles all that concatenation for you and also provides its own `get_feature_names`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **graphviz** instead. and use the following code to view the decision tree with feature names.

```
import pydotplus
import sklearn.tree as tree
from IPython.display import Image

dt_feature_names = list(X.columns)
dt_target_names = [str(s) for s in Y.unique()]
tree.export_graphviz(dt, out_file='tree.dot', 
    feature_names=dt_feature_names, class_names=dt_target_names,
    filled=True)  
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_file('tree.dot')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

This will display feature names with values, gini coefficient, sample, value and class

Comment: This won't work, I have main problem in collecting feature names, feature names are build when the model is fitted, in my case I have total 6689 features. I got to know exact number when it throwed an error. Now I don't know how to extract features